# How and where to implement IVsMultiViewDocumentView

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to create a custom editor for Visual Studio.

So far I have implemented the 'design' portion (the file type opens in this view by default). Now I would like to implement a 'code-view' with the 'design-view' (Similar to the xaml design editor).

My research says to use the IVsMultiViewDocumentView interface, but was vague on where and how to implement this interface. Some assistance on the matter would be greatly appreciated